# Why does Cesium viewer not display a model, when I add it?

Tags: javascript, java, angularjs, spring-boot, cesiumjs

I have an application, which displays a 3D map of a city and the "Add building" button.

When the user presses that button, a model of a building must be inserted into the map.

But it doesn't - I see a selection marker at the correct place, but no actual building.

**Method 1**

I add the building using following code (see file `src\main\resources\static\js\myapp.js` the source code):

```
function addBuilding() {
  var position = Cesium.Cartesian3.fromDegrees(132.159633, 43.350116, 0.);
  createModel('/models/CesiumAir/Cesium_Air.gltf', position);
}

function createModel(url, position) {
    var heading = Cesium.Math.toRadians(135);
    var pitch = 0;
    var roll = 0;
    var orientation = Cesium.Transforms.headingPitchRollQuaternion(
        position, heading, pitch, roll);

    var entity = viewer.entities.add({
        name : url,
        position : position,
        orientation : orientation,
        model : {
            uri : url,
            minimumPixelSize : 128
        }
    });
    console.log("entity.model = " + entity.model);
    viewer.selectedEntity = entity;
}
```

This didn't work, so I tried another method.

**Method 2**

```
var scene = viewer.scene;
var modelMatrix = Cesium.Transforms.eastNorthUpToFixedFrame(
    Cesium.Cartesian3.fromDegrees(132.159633, 43.350116, 0.0));
var primitive = Cesium.Model.fromGltf({
                      url : '/models/CesiumAir/Cesium_Air.gltf',
                      modelMatrix : modelMatrix,
                      minimumPixelSize : 128,
                      appearance : new Cesium.DebugAppearance({
                          attributeName : 'normal'
                        })
                  });
scene.primitives.add(primitive);
```

This didn't work, either.

If I open the URL `http://localhost:8080/models/CesiumAir/Cesium_Air.gltf` in the browser, I can see some JSON output, so a broken link isn't the cause.

I'd appreciate, if you told me, what I have to modify in my program to make adding of buildings work. The source code and the building instructions are available [here](http://bit.ly/1RN7UKq). The application uses AngularJS, maybe Cesium and Angular interfere somehow.

This [video](http://youtu.be/EGGSFf7ThWM) shows, how to reproduce this error.

**Update 1:** When I open the page I sometimes (but not always) get the following exception (when I enable stopping on uncaught exceptions):

[image: Error]

Comment: Your model code is fine, in fact if you paste Method 1 into [Cesium Sandcastle](http://cesiumjs.org/Cesium/Apps/Sandcastle/index.html) and fix the URL, the model loads exactly as expected.  The problem is a bug elsewhere in your code and you are simply seeing it manifest in the form of the model not showing up.

Comment: Are there any errors that show up in the web console?  (F12, console tab)

Comment: @emackey Yes. See my update 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When creating your viewer in myapp.js, change `Cesium.SceneMode.COLUMBUS_VIEW` to `Cesium.SceneMode.SCENE3D`.  [Model rendering is currently not supported outside of 3D mode](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/cesium-dev/suh5RmcP1Gc/l1CwrqaAn4YJ).

Comment: Thanks. This solved my problem. I will award the bounty to you as soon as possible (SO says in 16 hours).